# Colocar un valor mas la variable en un input con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas lo que deseo hacer es que dependiendo el valor que ingrese en el input me coloque una V- o E-, pero no me agrega cuando es E-, o si ya hay un V- no lo cambia. Adjunto el codigo.

```js
 function evaluarContenido(cadenaIngresada){
      var evaluarCadena = cadenaIngresada.split("");
      var cadena=parseInt(evaluarCadena);
        if (cadena < 80000000) {
          if(evaluarCadena[0] != 'V'){
            $("#DNI").val("V-"+cadenaIngresada);
          }
        }else{
          if(evaluarCadena[0] != 'E'){
            $("#DNI").val("E-"+cadenaIngresada);
          }
        }
    }
```

```css
.form-control {

  display: block;

  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;

  font-size: 1rem;

  line-height: 1.25em;

  color: #acaaa6;

  background-color: #fff;

  background-image: none;

  background-clip: padding-box;

  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);

  border-radius: 0; }
 .form-control-label {

  padding-top: 0.625rem; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="form-control-label">
                              Dni
                          </label>
<input class="form-control" name="DNI" id="DNI" value="" onchange="evaluarContenido(this.value)" maxlength="10" required="" type="text">
```

Comment: Estas intentando parsear un arreglo a entero por supuesto que solo convertira el primer elemento, te recomiendo que no separes con split tu cadena si luego deseas convertirla a entero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No he entendido bien cuál sería el sentido de hacer `split` de tu cadena.

Propongo esta solución, la cual te puede convenir. Explico en qué consiste:

- Sea cual sea el valor del `input`, le quitas todas las letras, conservando sólo los números mediante regex y almacenas en la variable `valor`. Es importante tener un dato sólo numérico para la evaluación que sigue y para la futura actualización del input mismo.
- Te vales de un operador ternario para evaluar `valor`, asignando `V-` o `E-` a la variable `letra` según el caso.
- Finalmente, combinas `letra` y `valor` para actualizar el contenido del `input`.

De este modo el código queda independiente y le pones la letra solamente al final.

```js
document.getElementById("DNI").onchange = function() {
  var valor = this.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
  var letra = (valor < 80000000) ? "V-": "E-";
  this.value = letra + valor;
}
```

```html
<label class="form-control-label">
Dni
</label>
<input class="form-control" name="DNI" id="DNI" value="" maxlength="10" required="" type="text">
```

Como dato adicional, yo he sacado la función que escucha el  `onChange` del elemento HTML. Considero que es una mejor práctica, mientras más independiente sea el HTML mejor, de ese modo, si hay cualquier cambio (por ejemplo que por algún motivo quieras llamar a la función de otro modo y dicha función se use en inputs de distintos documentos, sólo cambias una sola vez, en el Javascript, no en el HTML. No obstante, puedes hacerlo como lo tenías, si así lo prefieres.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio, y si quiero colocar un "-" antes del ultimo número como sería?

Comment: @rosibelvicent me alegra de que te haya servido. Lo que pides en tu comentario sería como agregar una máscara al valor del DNI. Se trata de una pregunta interesante la cual es mucho más conveniente plantear en una nueva pregunta por dos motivos: podrás obtener varias respuestas y quedarte con la mejor, y la nueva pregunta/respuesta será mucho más útil para usuarios que tengan situaciones similares. Dicha pregunta aparte de la etiqueta `Javascript` debería tener también la etiqueta `regex`. En SO hay usuarios expertos en regex que te darán sin duda una respuesta óptima.